# How does flutter VSCode snippets to extract widget work?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

When I use VSCode snippet `Extract Widget`, I have the following :

```dart
class MyExtractedWidget extends StatelessWidget {
    const MyExtractedWidget({
        Key key,
        @required T someVariable,
    }) : _someVariable = someVariable,
        super(key: key);
    final T _someVariable;

    @override 
    Widget build(BuildContext context){ return Container(); }
}
```

However, I am used to write constructors the following way :

```dart
class MyExtractedWidget extends StatelessWidget {
    const MyExtractedWidget({
        Key key,
        @required this.someVariable, // Directly accessing variable using "this"
    }) : super(key: key);
    final T someVariable;

    @override 
    Widget build(BuildContext context){ return Container(); }
}
```

Do you know why snippets' constructors use a temporary variable instead of directly writing in the variable?

Is it related to encapsulation? If yes, I cannot understand why, as an extracted Widget is written in the same file, and that "underscored" variables are accessible in whole file.

#### EDIT

I tried with another widget and I have a kind of mix :

```dart
class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  const Test({
    Key key,
    @required List<SortedExpense> sortedExpenses,
    @required this.expensesSink,
  }) : _sortedExpenses = sortedExpenses, super(key: key);

  final List<SortedExpense> _sortedExpenses;
  final StreamSink<List<Expense>> expensesSink;
...
```

Comment: That's not how it behaves for me. It generates exactly the same thing as what you're used to.

Comment: Well now that's interesting, I tried with another widget and I have a mix of both (editted post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is based on the privacy of the variables you're extracting.

For example, the following widget:

```dart
Text(_count.toString())
```

will generate:

```dart
class MyName extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyName({
    Key key,
    @required int count,
  }) : _count = count, super(key: key);

  final int _count;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(_count.toString());
  }
}
```

while this widget:

```dart
Text(count.toString())
```

will create:

```dart
class MyName extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyName({
    Key key,
    @required this.count,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final int count;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(count.toString());
  }
}
```